# File.createTempFile(title, ext).getTotalSpace() returns a wrong result

Tags: java, java-io

I am using `File file = File.createTempFile(title, ext);` in order to create a temporary file which should be removed after method finishes processing. I also need to make some size checks on it after creation and this fails because the `file.getTotalSpace();` returns a huge number - "238857973760" - almost 2 terabits. The actual file that is created in the tmp folder is 1KB. Also, I only have 250 GB ... so I do not know what is with this value.

Any ideas why this method is going rogue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the JavaDoc of the method getTotalSpace():

> Returns the size of the partition named by this abstract pathname.

It does not return the size of your file, but of the partition on your disk (but may return an invalid value if it cannot determine it, like on network disk).

Use file.length() instead if you want to get the size of a file.

Answer (score 2):

`file.getTotalSpace()` returns size of partition in bytes. You can use `file.length()`

Answer (score 2):

Asserting others ,
You can use file.length(), if you want to get the size of file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Example : [here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_files_read.asp)

Method of File : [here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_files.asp)

use length method:

```
System.out.println("size of file is"+file.length());
```

returns file size in bytes